# How do i delete any characters from an array in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, chomp

I have an array list of email address and i want to delete eveything after the ";"

i tried chomp. but that didnt seem to work.

How would i loop through the array and remove everything after the ";" in my view.

Comment: can you give us an example of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
["aaaa;bbb"].map { |e| e.gsub(/;.*/, ';') }
```

From documentation: `gsub` returns a copy of str with the all occurrences of pattern substituted for the second argument.

So this regexp will match `;` and any character after, so you have to pass `;` as second argument.

Comment: Worked perfectly. thanks you. I couldn't wrap my head around it.